# How to parse this json example with SwiftyJSON?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

```
{"title" : "saved users", "saved_users_list" :

[
{"username" : "Danny7", "name" : "Danny", "email" : "danny@email.com"},

{"username" : "Ike2016", "name" : "Ike", "email" : "ike@email.com"},

{"username" : "john202", "name" : "John", "email" : "john@email.com"},

{"username" : "ray_mundo", "name" : "Raymundo", "email" : "ray@email.com"}

]
}
```

I'm trying to parse this json with SwiftyJSON and it isn't working.

```
json["saved_users_list"].count == 0

json["saved_users_list"][0]["username"] does not equal "Danny7"

json["title"] == null
```

Here's how I got the data:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters).validate().responseString { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    value = JSON(value)
                    print(value)
                }
        }
```

print(value) prints the json listed above.

Comment: Can you share your code so far? (E.g. how are you parsing the JSON? And how do you know it looks like what you've shared here?)

Comment: Oh yeah it might be I'm not converting string to json correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try put `JSON(value)` like this

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let value) :
            let swiftyJSON = JSON(value)
            print(swiftyJSON)
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You had it right.  I was accidentally doing a .GET for some reason when it needed to be a .POST.  I was actually getting an empty json object when doing a .GET.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Alamofire generally try to parse JSON for you? See if your code works better if you use `responseJSON` and don't call `JSON(...)` yourself. I.e.:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .Success:
        if let value = response.result.value {
            print(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: value would be a string then, and i can't parse strings with SwfityJSON

Comment: @walton Oh, sorry, need to use `responseJSON` if you want Alamofire to parse the JSON for you. See my edit, though your code should do pretty much the same thing. This will be hard to debug without seeing the exact string you're parsing or being able to reproduce by knowing the URL and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

aHope this class solves your issue, it's generated using SwiftyJSONAccelerator model generator.

```
public class BaseClass: NSObject, NSCoding {

// MARK: Declaration for string constants to be used to decode and also serialize.
internal let kBaseClassTitleKey: String = "title"
internal let kBaseClassSavedUsersListKey: String = "saved_users_list"


// MARK: Properties
public var title: String?
public var savedUsersList: [SavedUsersList]?


// MARK: SwiftyJSON Initalizers
/**
Initates the class based on the object
- parameter object: The object of either Dictionary or Array kind that was passed.
- returns: An initalized instance of the class.
*/
convenience public init(object: AnyObject) {
    self.init(json: JSON(object))
}

/**
Initates the class based on the JSON that was passed.
- parameter json: JSON object from SwiftyJSON.
- returns: An initalized instance of the class.
*/
public init(json: JSON) {
    title = json[kBaseClassTitleKey].string
    savedUsersList = []
    if let items = json[kBaseClassSavedUsersListKey].array {
        for item in items {
            savedUsersList?.append(SavedUsersList(json: item))
        }
    } else {
        savedUsersList = nil
    }

}


/**
Generates description of the object in the form of a NSDictionary.
- returns: A Key value pair containing all valid values in the object.
*/
public func dictionaryRepresentation() -> [String : AnyObject ] {

    var dictionary: [String : AnyObject ] = [ : ]
    if title != nil {
        dictionary.updateValue(title!, forKey: kBaseClassTitleKey)
    }
    if savedUsersList?.count > 0 {
        var temp: [AnyObject] = []
        for item in savedUsersList! {
            temp.append(item.dictionaryRepresentation())
        }
        dictionary.updateValue(temp, forKey: kBaseClassSavedUsersListKey)
    }

    return dictionary
}

// MARK: NSCoding Protocol
required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.title = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(kBaseClassTitleKey) as? String
    self.savedUsersList = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(kBaseClassSavedUsersListKey) as? [SavedUsersList]

}

public func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(title, forKey: kBaseClassTitleKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(savedUsersList, forKey: kBaseClassSavedUsersListKey)

}

}
```